# How to check whether a theme on themeforest.net will work with php

Tags: php, codeigniter, themes

I am planning to buy a theme from themeforest.net .I want to ask, how is it possible to make sure that a theme would work with php(codeigniter) mvc structure?

My fiend bought [this theme](http://themeforest.net/item/minovate-angular-admin-dashboard/10068009) but this was coded in angular js and hence couldn't work with php mvc, most probably

Comment: The theme is called "Angular Admin Dashboard"... he did not know that it was coded in angular? Anyway, read the comments to the theme. If the author did a poor job describing how the theme works, then post a comment yourself. I am not sure what other kinds of answers you are expecting.

Comment: you can use css/html and code it yourself. this would be much better from duplicating exactly , or you can buy another theme.

Comment: He knew, but the question is no theme says php theme, but some supports php mvc, how to differe b/w php and other themes

Comment: If it works with php it will work with CI too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look for html/css themes they are simple html/css coded themes

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter is a php framework, html template has nothing to do with it. What do you mean anyway? What are you worrying about? Im pretty sure it would work.

Comment: Angular themes too or not?

Comment: depends on what you're using. If you do use angular or know how to use it then definitely it would work.